# How do I create a function for two-dimensional array search?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

please help me,
I have a function to search for one-dimensional arrays, here are the source codes and their variables:

```
var fruits= ["Apple","Banana","Grape","Orange"];

function searchStringInArray (src1,fruits) 
{
  var res=""
  for (var j=0; j<src1.length; j++) {
    if (src1[j].match (searched)) 
    {
    res=res+src1[j]+","
    }
}
    return res;
} 
alert(searchStringInArray (src1,'Grape'));
```

but I want to modify the function to search for multidimensional arrays, with the following variables:

```
var fruits= [
    ["001","Apple","For John"],[["002","Banana","For Stuart"],["003","Grape","For Collins"],["004","Orange","For Ben"]
    ];
```

Approximately how the function is suitable for the variable?

Comment: If you want to continue the same code only then you have to put 1 more loop to process multi array.

Comment: please give me an example of the source code :)

Comment: what is 'src1' ?

Comment: @AnkitPandey I think it's supposed to be the `fruits` array.

Comment: oh sorry, it should be: alert (searchStringInArray (fruits, 'Grape'))

Comment: There are still problems with your code. For instance, what is `searched`?

Comment: Suppose I type search String In Array (fruits, 'Grape')
and how the output can appear:
ID: 003.
Fruits: Grape
Receiver: For Collins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more convenient way to use this with the prototype.

```js
const fruits = [
  ["001", "Apple", "For John"],
  ["002", "Banana", "For Stuart"],
  ["003", "Grape", "For Collins"],
  ["004", "Orange", "For Ben"]
]

Array.prototype.searchIn2DArray = function(fruitsName){
  let searched = false;
  for(let j=0; j<this.length; j++){
    if(this[j].indexOf(fruitsName) > -1){
      return this[j];
    }
  }
  return searched;
}

console.log(fruits.searchIn2DArray('Orange'));
```

Comment: Really, this isn't the best way to perform the operation; you should be using something like [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).  If you're going to do it manually, then try a binary approach to the test, so you're not looking at every single element.

Comment: @Paul, Thanks for the comment. But I am looking at all elements till not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combined with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const fruits = [
  ["001", "Apple", "For John"],
  ["002", "Banana", "For Stuart"],
  ["003", "Grape", "For Collins"],
  ["004", "Orange", "For Ben"]
]

const searchStringInArray = (src1, searched) => src1.find(arr => arr.includes(searched))
  
console.log(searchStringInArray(fruits, 'Grape'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(f of fruits){data=f.filter(s => s==="Apple").length > 0;
console.log(data); if(data){console.log("found");filteredD.push(f);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to flat your multidimensional array and then find desired item:

```js
const fruits= [
    ["001","Apple","For John"]
    ,[
        ["002","Banana","For Stuart"],
        ["003","Grape","For Collins"],
        ["004","Orange","For Ben"]
    ]
];

const flatArray = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
      return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatArray(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
    }, []);
  }

const flattened = flatArray(fruits);
const fruitToFind = 'Grape';
const result = flattened.find(f=> f === fruitToFind);
console.log(result);
```